# I want to get unique set of n*n arrays which are including only 0 or 1 at random location in c++

Tags: c++

I want to acquire set of n*n arrays including 0 or 1

But, each element has to be different each other.

For example,

```
arr[3][3] = {{0,1,0},
             {1,0,0},
             {1,1,1}}
arr2[3][3] = {{0,1,1},
              {1,1,1},
              {0,0,1}}
```

Like above, I need unique array.

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you need to generate them yourself ? Or do you simply need them generated and provided ?

Comment: I want to generate them using c++.

Answer (score 1):

For an array of N elements, take an N-bit number and use it as a counter. For each N-bit value, create an array with one of the bits from the counter in each element of the array. This will generate 2<sup>N</sup> unique arrays (i.e., the maximum possible for that number of `0`s and `1`s).

Comment: As I understand your answer,
if I want unique arr[3][3], 
then make random binary number in 0~2^9-1
For example, if I generate binary number 011100111 
             then change this to arr[3][3] = {{0,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1}}
right?? 

Then, Is it possible to make more than random 2^64 binary number in c++? I need to generate random 100 by 100 array or more.

Comment: @user2067011: The built in types only go up to 64 bits (at least in most implementations), but there are quite a few libraries around to deal with arbitrary-sized integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [`next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) for this. The following gets you every combination of an n sized array of 0's and 1's:

```
std::vector<int> root(4, 1);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(1, root);

for(auto i = root.begin(); i != root.end(); ++i)
{
    *i = 0;
    do {
        vec.push_back(root);
    } while(std::next_permutation(root.begin(), root.end()));
}
```

Here, `n` is 4. But you could make it anything. The combinations are contained in `vec`.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrices are large (n >= 12), then you can simply generate a random matrix and with *overwhelming* probability (assuming your PRNG is good), you will get unique matrices. (The odds of two random 12x12 matrices being identical is less than one in 2^70, or about 1 in 10^21).

In C++11, you can use the `mt19937` random-number generator to produce a large number of high-quality random numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

main() {
    std::mt19937 generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,1);
    int n = 12;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            std::cout << distribution(generator);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
101101101001
001111110111
100110000011
111111001011
101110001000
110001000111
100110010000
101000000011
111101101101
000111011100
110111101011
100100011100
```